# How to store a the values returned from List Should Contain Sub List in robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Below sample script returns **Tamilnadu** after using *List Should Contain Sub List*

How can I store the returned records in a New List?

```
@{List1}= Assam  Bihar  Tamilnadu
@{List2}= Assam  Bihar

List Should Contain Sub List      ${List2}      ${List1}      values=True
```

Sample Output:
Following values were not found from first list: (Tamilnadu)

Comment: The purpose of `List Should Contain Sub List` is not to return values - it doesn't return anything, but to do assertion - that one (presumably bigger) list has as members all members of another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do a difference of List1 - List2, so you can use keyword `Remove Values From List`:

```
*** Settings *** 
Library    Collections    

*** Test Cases *** 
List Difference
    ${List1}=     Create List    Assam  Bihar  Tamilnadu
    ${List2}=     Create List    Assam  Bihar
    Remove Values From List    ${List1}    @{List2}
    Log    ${List1}
```

`${List1}` will contain `Tamilnadu`.

If you don't want to change either list, you can create your own keyword.

First a custom Python library:

**ListDiff.py**:

```py
def list_difference(first, second):
    second = set(second)
    return [item for item in first if item not in second]
```

Now you import it into RF:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ListDiff.py
```

and you use it in a testcase:

```
*** Test Cases *** 
List Difference
    ${List1}=     Create List    Assam  Bihar  Tamilnadu
    ${List2}=     Create List    Assam  Bihar
    ${Diff}=    List Difference    ${List1}    ${List2}
```

This will assign `Tamilnadu` into `${Diff}`.